# Creating a column in Python

Tags: python

I'am trying to create categories for a column Age, with the following python code:

```
for x in range(len(Ttrain.Age)):
       if Ttrain.Age(x) == 0:
             Ttrain.Age_Group(x) == 'Missing'
        elif 0 < Ttrain.Age(x) <= 18:
             Ttrain.Age_Group(x) == 'Young'
        elif 19 < Ttrain.Age(x) <= 40:
             Ttrain.Age_Group(x) == 'Adult'
        elif 41 < Ttrain.Age(x) <= 60:
             Ttrain.Age_Group(x) == 'Middle_Aged'
        elif Ttrain.Age(x) > 60:
             Ttrain.Age_Group(x) == 'Old'
 % (x)
```

Such that the Age_Group column will contain the categories. But I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable

Please note that I have replaced all the missing values in age column with 0.

Comment: It eludes me why you would try and tackle a learning problem when the basics of the language are not understood. That is bound to keep running into problems. As for two hints I can give you right off the bat: the error tells you what is wrong. You invoke the `__call__` method by using `( )` parentheses, which is not valid for a `Series` object. Using square brackets will let you access indices. A second hint is that you are not setting anything. All of the `if` clauses result in another comparison which will not change anything in your `Ttrain.Age_Group` Series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many problems in your code which, as @Uvar mentioned in the comments, indicate that you do not have a good grasp of the fundamentals of `python`. I highly recommend that you read one of the *many* tutorials available for free online for both `python` and `pandas`.

Let me try to explain some of your errors, fix your code, and try to provide a better solution.

#### Function Calls (`__call__`) vs. Getting Items (`__getitem__`)

Parentheses in python `()` refer to function calls. When you write `if Ttrain.Age(x) == 0:`, what you want to do is access the `x`-th element of the `Series` `Ttrain.Age`. But the interpreter thinks you want to call the `Series` as a function (hence your error message). The correct syntax is to use square brackets `[]` for indexing: `if Ttrain.Age[x] == 0:`

#### Assignment vs. Equality

Double equal signs (`==`) is used to test for equality. A single equal (`=`) sign is for assignment.

`Ttrain.Age_Group[x] == 'Missing'` is testing to see if the `x`-th element in the `Series` `Ttrain.Age_Group` equals the `string` `'Missing'`. What you meant to write was: `Ttrain.Age_Group[x] = 'Missing'`

#### Access before initialization

Putting the above two points together:

```
for x in range(len(Ttrain)):
       if Ttrain.Age[x] == 0:
             Ttrain.Age_Group[x] = 'Missing'

...
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Age_Group'
```

This is because the `Age_Group` series does not yet exist, so the interpreter doesn't know what to do. You need to first define this column.

```
Ttrain['Age_Group'] = None
for x in range(len(Ttrain)):
    if Ttrain.Age[x] == 0:
         Ttrain.Age_Group[x] = 'Missing'
```

But doing this will cause the following warning:

> SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame

This is a bad thing. I'm not going to go into the details. I'll leave it as an exercise for you to [research and understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) why.

#### Putting it all together

Here is a cleaned up version of your code. You will notice that I have also changed the `elif` conditions. I'll leave that up to you to think about why.

```
import pandas as pd
# mock up some dummy data
Ttrain = pd.DataFrame({'Age': range(0, 80, 10)})
# Ttrain['Age_Group'] = None  # don't need this since we're using loc
for x in range(len(Ttrain)):
    if Ttrain.Age[x] == 0:
         Ttrain.loc[x, 'Age_Group'] = 'Missing'
    elif Ttrain.Age[x] <= 18:
         Ttrain.loc[x, 'Age_Group'] = 'Young'
    elif Ttrain.Age[x] <= 40:
         Ttrain.loc[x, 'Age_Group'] = 'Adult'
    elif Ttrain.Age[x] <= 60:
         Ttrain.loc[x, 'Age_Group'] = 'Middle_Aged'
    elif Ttrain.Age[x] > 60:
         Ttrain.loc[x, 'Age_Group'] = 'Old'
```

#### A better way

In general, iterating through a `dataframe` is bad. It's slow and in many cases, there's a better way to do what you're trying to do. Sometimes, it's unavoidable but that's not the case in this example. (Look up pandas masks).

```
import pandas as pd

# create a dummy dataset for this example
Ttrain = pd.DataFrame({'Age': range(0, 80, 10)})

Ttrain.loc[Ttrain.Age == 0, 'Age_Group'] = 'Missing'
Ttrain.loc[(Ttrain.Age > 0) & (Ttrain.Age <= 18), 'Age_Group'] = 'Young'
Ttrain.loc[(Ttrain.Age > 18) & (Ttrain.Age <= 40), 'Age_Group'] = 'Adult'
Ttrain.loc[(Ttrain.Age > 40) & (Ttrain.Age <= 60), 'Age_Group'] = 'Middle_Aged'
Ttrain.loc[(Ttrain.Age > 60), 'Age_Group'] = 'Old'
```

#### Final output

This is what the final dataframe looks like:

```
>>> print(Ttrain)

   Age    Age_Group
0    0      Missing
1   10        Young
2   20        Adult
3   30        Adult
4   40        Adult
5   50  Middle_Aged
6   60  Middle_Aged
7   70          Old
```

Good luck.